# In c++, how to wrap default headers with fallback

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Say my code uses std::array, I'd like to do:

file: array

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MY_TOOLSET_HAS_STD_ARRAY
#include <array> //recursive include here?
#else
#include <boost/array.hpp>
namespace std
{
   using boost::array;
}
#endif
```

Such that my project can use std::array without caring about the compiler/platform. One problem (at least) is that when std::array is available, the include will be recursive, when what I really want is (semantically) "include the header that would have been included if this include didn't exist".

Any ideas on how to do this? I know pulling boost::array into std might be considered bad practice as well, so I'm interested about thoughts on that as well.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. Use one of the other.

Comment: For the case of `array` Boost.TR1 should do The Right Thing.

Comment: It's actually technically undefined behaviour to put stuff in `std`, not bad practice (but before nasal demons are invoked, it should work just fine). I think you're best off just naming your header something different (or putting it in a different directory, like Boost has done).

Comment: Why not just use `boost::array` if you need to deal with pre-C++11 compilers? And even in that case, it's very likely you have access to `std::tr1::array` available in `<tr1/array>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Right Way to solve this "problem" is to not introduce it in the first place.

If some of your build environments support C++11 but others don't, then find a common subset that is supported under all your build environments and use that.  In this case, that common subset appears to be Boost.  So you should use `boost::array`.

Consider also that if you develop & test using `std::array`, then you have left an entire code branch untested -- the one using `boost::array`.

I'm all for lazy programming -- but *smart* lazy programming.  Lazy programming doesn't mean hacky or clumsy programming, and smart lazy programming doesn't invoke Undefined Behavior, as adding `boost::array` to the `std` namespace would.  Saying "I don't want to go through all my code and change `std::array` to `boost::array`" isn't a good reason to introduce hacks and undefined behavior.  It could be as simple as invoking `sed` to make all these changes, and it might take you only 5 minutes.

Comment: So I don't disagree...and that's one option. But this is a project with many people working on it, and it would have been nice to handle the case where everyone didn't know "oh, I have to use boost::array"...because <array> works on the platform they're developing on.

Comment: @user109078 Unfortunately that's a problem for your managers to solve.

Comment: Developers should not be developing with a compiler that isn't used in Prod.

Comment: They are, but we release for windows and for linux...and they use Visual Studio on windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the pre-C++11 "template typedef workaround" for this, which does not involve #defining type names, but does make the syntax of using the type a bit uglier:

```
#ifdef MY_TOOLSET_HAS_STD_ARRAY
    #include <array>
#else
    #include <boost/array.hpp>
#endif

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct fixed_array
{
    #ifdef MY_TOOLSET_HAS_STD_ARRAY
        typedef std::array<T, N> type;
    #else
        typedef boost::array<T, N> type;
    #endif
};
```

Then your usage of the type becomes:

```
typename fixed_array<char, 4>::type some_chars;
```

However, it would be considerably simpler just to use `boost::array`.  It means fewer permutations you have to test and therefore lowers maintenance cost on the codebase.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely one of those use-cases for macros:

```
// in "my_fixed_array.h"
#ifdef MY_TOOLEST_HAS_STD_ARRAY
    #include <array>
    #define FIX_ARRAY std::array
#else
    #include <boost/array.hpp>
    #define FIX_ARRAY boost::array
#fi


// anywhere else
#include "my_fixed_array.h"
FIX_ARRAY<char, 4> some_chars;
```

That way you don't have to go around doing naughty things like putting stuff into `namespace std`.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but personally I'd rather (illegally) extend `std` than use macros for typenames...

Comment: @Cameron I'd rather use the macros. At least the resulting code would be legal.

Comment: @Cameron You don't need macros. Use `namespace my { #ifdef MY_TOOLEST_HAS_STD_ARRAY using array = std::array; #else using array = boost::array; #endif }`.

Comment: What about creating a templated class that inherits from one of the arrays.

Comment: No need of macro, you may use `typedef` (with templated `using`).

Comment: @Praetorian I assumed the point of the exercise is that C++11 is not available.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yeah, fair enough. I'd personally just stick to using `boost::array` everywhere if you need to support older compilers as well.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Does Praetorian's solution require C++11? It doesn't appear to me that it does.

Comment: @FredLarson You'd have to do `template <typename T, size_t N> using array = boost::array<T,N>;`

Comment: @FredLarson The alias template syntax does require C++11. I messed up the earlier comment anyway, missing type arguments. Should be `template<typename T, std::size_t N> using array = std::array<T, N>;` and so on.

Comment: @FredLarson `using` syntax is C++11-only. However, you can do `template <typename T, size_t N> struct fixed_array { #ifdef MY_TOOLSET_HAS_STD_ARRAY typedef std::array<T, N> type; #else typedef boost::array<T, N> type; #endif };` and use `typename fixed_array<char, 4>::type some_chars;`.

Comment: @cdhowie You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how sane your compiler implementation is (and most are pretty good in this respect), you can simply rely on the include path search order. Default system include paths are normally searched before user-specified "additional" include paths.

So if you have a header named `array` that's in a non-standard include path, you can assume that it will *only* be included *if the standard `<array>` header is not present*, since the system one would be found first otherwise. Note that you don't even need the feature detection goop using this technique.

(I didn't say it was pretty -- this is a bit of an abuse of the build environment, albeit a fairly safe one.)